# Path With Path Transition

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

This is the case:
I want a path go along another path with animation. for example I have to pathA and pathB which have the same shape, pathA is red and bold and pathB is black and thin.

I want to fill pathB with pathA. animation should start from the beginning of the path and continues till the end, so pathA should start filling pathB from beginning of it and continues till the end of it.

My goal is to create progress bar with any possible shape, curve, zigzag and so on.

Comment: Sounds great!  Where are you stuck?  Any code?  Or can you describe the detail of your current approach?

Comment: Well @jewelsea, what I have now is far from what I want. It's just circle with path transition. I'm trying to calculate the length of path and fill it with many circles, but I don't know how to calculate the length of path :D

Comment: maybe this article will help you http://www.hameister.org/JavaFX_SVGPath.html

Comment: Thanks @agonist_ but it couldn't help me.